# Calculate the quality of image on 1 years analysis for specific region

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to determine the quality of LST_modis product (ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1")) in somewhere in IRAN. The aim of my project is to illustrate the proportion of good quality pixels for each day in 2019.
so I need to calculate the 365 number; for example, this data can be like  80% or 95%,...
my question is how I can write a function to extract the data quality from QC bitmask? in this dataset, we have "QC_Day" with this detail:

QC_details

Bits 0-1: Mandatory QA flags
0: LST produced, good quality, not necessary to examine more detailed QA

---

I used this code to extract data with 0 flags(good quality), and I don't know it is working correctly or not!!
my exact problem is with `cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(1).int()`. pow (1) or pow(0)?

```
var LST = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1")
.filterBounds(uremia)
.filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-01-02')
.map(function(img){
  return img.clip(uremia);});
function QC_control(image){
    var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(1).int();
    var qa = image.select('QC_Day');
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    return image.updateMask(mask)
    .select("LST_Day_1km")
    .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);}
    
var cloud_masked = LST.map(QC_control)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always found working with these bitmasks very fiddly and error prone, so I've created a little utility function, which I keep on reusing:

```
function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
```

According to the [EE catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MOD11A1):

> Bits 0-1: Mandatory QA flags
>
> ```
> 0: LST produced, good quality, not necessary to examine more detailed QA
> 1: LST produced, other quality, recommend examination of more detailed QA
> 2: LST not produced due to cloud effects
> 3: LST not produced primarily due to reasons other than cloud
> ```

To get the quality of an image, you'd do this:

```
var qa = image.select('QC_Day');
var quality = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0, 1) // Bits 0-1, giving quality between 0 and 3
```

Finally, here's a script that extract your daily proportion:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0379544955f71a3b01a70d8a8caef774